# Alpha-numeric Random number generator for Apache module

Tags: c, apache

I need a random number generator for Apache module in C, that generates Alpha-numeric values. I tried `Apr_generate_random_bytes()` and a whole suite of Apr_random functions as in [here](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group__apr__random.html), but all I get is - all characters from 0-255, but I need characters that only represent 0-9 and a-z A-Z in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

This leaves you with a range of 10 + 26 + 26 = 62 characters, pretty close to 64, which is conveniently a power of 2. Make an array of 64 character entries with alphanumeric values and 2 additional characters (`-` and `_`, maybe? Otherwise repeat other numbers), get a convenient number of random bytes, read 7 bits at a time from it and use the character given in your lookup table.